# What is the 4th Dimension?

Tags: logic

I don't think that the fourth dimension would be time, if it were discovered. Time is a measure of physical change that presumably should exist in and separately from all conceivable (and otherwise) dimensions of space. Time is itself only a measure of change in the physical world. The fourth dimension, instead, is a dimension of space that we humans cannot possibly imagine, because we have no way of observing it.

It's akin to a 2D shape living on a 2D plane and trying to imagine the 3rd dimension. He understands length and height, but width would be impossible to imagine if he tried. He wouldn't even know TO try because he doesn't understand its existence. It's a direction that he can't move in. It should be noted that this being would surely experience time, because time is a measure of change, even in this strange two-dimensional reality.
This is very much like our situation. We live in the third dimension, in a three-dimensional universe. We can move in three different directions. Up, down, and side to side. The fourth dimension is an unimaginable (but completely reasonable to a fourth dimensional observer) direction to move in. We can't imagine it, just like a 2 dimensional being couldn't imagine moving into the third dimension, but it would seem so simple to us three-dimensional people.

Presuming that the fourth dimension is time is ridiculous in the following way. 
Imagine that the two dimensional being mentioned before, and I see no reason why they wouldn't experience time, had a breakthrough. He thinks he's discovered the what the third dimension is! It's obviously time, because that's multiple 2 dimensional spaces, right? Well, we as third dimensional beings know that that's wrong. The fatal flaw in his theory is that there is in fact a different direction that he doesn't know about. 
So why would the fourth dimension not follow this pattern? It makes more sense to think of the fourth dimension as a mysterious, unimaginable new direction or dimension of space.

Comment: When referring to time as the fourth dimension, this is most likely due to people referring to *spacetime*, which is used in cosmology. Time as a fourth dimension is not intended to be interpreted as a spacial dimension, but a temporal dimension. While you can consider time to be the fourth dimension, that is simply grouping both types of dimensions together. There is no fourth spacial dimension that we can currently prove. But if **a** fourth dimension not does *not* have t

Comment: You are quite right, in my opinion. Yet you do not seem to have examined the underlying and assumed concept "dimension." As always, start with the history and etymology.

Comment: Could you make clear what the issue in philosophy is that you're asking about? I see a question about dimensions that might be better addressed in math or physics but nothing specifically asking a question about philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

Remember a dimension in terms of physics is just a measurable feature of some situation or thing. One of the reasons time is often said to be the "4th" dimension is because it makes sense in the way that it can be viewed as a 3 dimensional cross section of 4d space-time.

To visualize why this makes sense, imagine a point in space; a 0 dimensional object. It has no width, length, or depth, it is just an infinitely small point in space. The more you zoom in doesn't change its size. Now imagine extending more points from this point, creating a line. A 1 dimensional object: there is only length, no height, or depth.

If you extend the line in the Y direction ( upwards ) at a right angle from the line you now could imagine you have a square. A 2 dimensional object.

To follow in this fashion imagine extending the square outward in the Z direction, towards you. You now have a cube. A 3 dimensional object.

A square is a **2 dimensional cross-section of a 3 dimensional cube**, a line is a **1 dimensional cross-section of a 2 dimensional square**, just as a point is a **0-dimensional cross-section of a 1 dimensional line**. So what is a 3 dimensional cross-section of a 4 dimensional object? Time fits this definition perfectly because if you could freeze time at any given moment, you would have a cross section of a continuous "time-line".

You are right, though. Time is not a spatial dimension. Time is a temporal dimension, and scientists disagree over whether time should or should not be the 4th dimension. It is quite possible to think of a 4th spatial dimension. This video is a good example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6kn6nXMWF0

There are even higher spatial dimensions that can be "imagined" which the video hints at. Remember that no one is really visualizing this well. Humans cannot yet visualize past 3 spatial dimensions, however they can be mathematically constructed.

Answer (score 0):

The limit to your logic is the assumption that "the fourth dimension" means a clearly specified dimension that 100% of people will all agree upon.  That agreement has never been achieved.  The best you could say is "a fourth dimension."

The funny thing is, it doesn't do what you say it does.  You say, "The fourth dimension, instead, is a dimension of space that we humans cannot possibly imagine, because we have no way of observing it."  That is actually false, because we have people who visualize four dimensional systems all the time.  In fact, if you're really feeling masochistic, you can explore infinite dimensional function spaces which are the basis of Quantum Mechanics.  Or, if those are too exotic, you can consider String Theory, which requires 11 dimensions to operate sanely.

You are welcome to suggest there is a fourth dimension which is spatial, and explore its properties.  However, to switch from the indefinite pronoun to the definite pronoun requires a level of agreement that is harder to get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I cannot follow your argument. But I accept your conclusion.

The problem lies, as far as I understand it,in the definition of dimensionality.

Here are two common definitions.

First, degrees of freedom. Ways or directions a "subject" could go. This is very messy, yet a largely satisfactory "phenomenological" understanding of the term.

Second, "number of numbers" required to specify a point. This is an even messier definition, since "number" is ill-defined or controversial to begin with.

Space and time are apples and oranges, as Bergson suggests. Not the same sorts of perspectives. The concept "dimension," under which they are placed, is in my own view fragile and corrupt.

The word "dimension" and the whole concept badly needs redefinition. The mathematical definitions, as in string theory, are so far beyond intuition, so "formal" that the word "dimension" no longer makes physical sense.

To adhere to some concept called "dimension," that applies to both "depth perception" and "temporal sequences" makes very little sense.